# XDocument XPath + Regex element locator

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Is there an equivalent [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) node locator for Elements in [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)?

```
private const string InvalidDateTest = 
    "[text() = \"0000-00-00\" or text() = \"    -  -  \" or text() = \"-  -  \"]";

xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//DeterminedDate/Value" + InvalidDateTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

sauced it out myself:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

xDocument.XPathSelectElements("//DeterminedDate/Value" + InvalidDateTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

XDocument + Xpath sample :

```
using(var stream = new StringReader(xml))
{
    XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(stream);
    var query = (IEnumerable) xmlFile.XPathEvaluate("/REETA/AFFIDAVIT/COUNTY_NAME");
    foreach(var band in query.Cast < XElement > ())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(band.Value);
    }
    xmlFile.Save("books.xml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To discriminate the nodes you need to simply chain extensions to the descendant call which will filter out what is needed:

```
string Data = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<Notifications>
   <Alerts>
      <Alert>1</Alert>
      <Alert>2</Alert>
      <Alert>3</Alert>
   </Alerts>
</Notifications>";


XDocument.Parse(Data)
         .Descendants("Alert")
         .Where (node => int.Parse(node.Value) > 1 && int.Parse(node.Value) < 3)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(al => Console.WriteLine ( al.Value ) );       // 2 is the result
```